# Python | Trying to verify input is within list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to figure out why this code isn't exiting the program upon entering one of the exit commands within the created list.

```
from sys import exit

Exit_Commands = [
    "Exit"
    "exit"
    "Goodbye"
    "goodbye"
    "Bye"
    'bye'
]

Alive = True

while Alive:
    User_Input_From_Console = input()

    if User_Input_From_Console in Exit_Commands:
        print("Exiting Program")
        exit()
```

Comment: It would print out the user input, why is that relevant? I'm not trying to print out the user input, I'm trying to compare it to other strings within a list.

Answer (score 2):

Add commas to your list:

```
Exit_Commands = [
    "Exit",
    "exit",
    "Goodbye",
    "goodbye",
    "Bye",
    'bye'
]
```

Without commas, all your strings were being implicitly concatenated together.

Comment: Wow. I just. I apologize.

Comment: @RobertReynolds it's a common mistake at all levels, no need to apologize.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import exit

Exit_Commands = [
    "Exit",
    "exit",
    "Goodbye",
    "goodbye",
    "Bye",
    'bye',
]

Alive = True

while Alive:
    User_Input_From_Console = input()

    if User_Input_From_Console in Exit_Commands:
        print("Exiting Program")
        exit()
```

Maybe this will work i am not 100% sure as i am also noob.